# In ngrx effect the operator after concatLatestFrom marks the action as type never

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm getting a TypeScript syntax error in the filter operator saying **Property "searchCriteria" does not exist on type "never".**

I must be failing in my understanding of concatLatestFrom because I can't get this operator to work (compile) in the effect and I can't find any other places where people are having a similar issue.

```
  loadSearchResults$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(searchActions.SearchApi.type),
    concatLatestFrom((action) =>
      this.searchStore.pipe(select(fromSearchSelectors.getSelectedRecordRangeResults))), 
    filter(([action, recordResultList]) => !recordResultList[createRowID(action.searchCriteria.recordRange)]),
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem,  `ofType(searchActions.SearchApi.type)` needed only `ofType(searchActions.SearchApi)`.  So I didn't need to give the "type" off the creator class.